# Rendering images and voxelizing the images

Tags: image, image-processing, graphics, 3d, computer-vision

I am using the shapenet dataset. From this dataset, I have 3d models in .obj format. I rendered the images of these 3d models using pyrender library which gives me an image like this :
[image]

Now I am using raycasting to voxelize this image. The voxel model I get is something like below :
[image]

I am not able to understand why I am getting the white or light brown colored artifacts in the boundary of the object.

The reason I could come up with was maybe the pixels at the boundary of the object contain two colors, so when I traverse the image as numpy array, I get an average of these two colors which gives me these artifacts. But I am not sure if this is the correct reason.

If anyone has any idea about what could be the reason, please let me know

Comment: I think the reason you mentioned is correct. For getting a better visualizing for "curves", it's better to interpolate some pixels at the border of the object and interpolation makes those light brown pixels. Although if you can define the shape in much more size (in pixels), your picture gets better.

Comment: We can;t really help much without code. Post a snippet